# Error while using dask to read in csv files

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dask

I am learning how to use dask.dataframe module to read in multiple csv files and when trying to read those, the error: `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer` is thrown.

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd


for year in range(2000, 2005):
    idx = pd.date_range(str(year), str(year + 1), freq='d', closed='left')
    pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randn(len(idx)), 
                  'B': np.random.randint(len(idx))},
                 index=idx).to_csv('{0}.csv'.format(year), index_label='date')


df = dd.read_csv('*.csv').set_index('date')
df.head()
```

Each year therefore looks something like this:

```
date              A           B
01/01/2000  1.13334261       135
02/01/2000  -1.071303513     135
03/01/2000  0.654942826      135
04/01/2000  0.452817638      135
05/01/2000  -2.400335129     135
06/01/2000  1.47236587       135
```

Comment: I don't see where dask is being used. Also from the error you mention, you should probably also show how your data looks like

Comment: @M.T Sorry, I have now edited the question

Comment: @M.T dask is applied at line 9 in the first snippet

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the data you provided given that I remove all space and replace it with commas in the sample data. pandas, and thus also dask typically set missing data to `NaN`. Try looking into [working with missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) for possible solutions. You could also try setting `verbose=True` in `read_csv`.

Comment: The small reproducible example is great.  Unfortunately I am also unable to reproduce the failure.  My first guess is that you have another CSV file in your directory that is being caught up by the `*.csv` globstring